# Search Console API: How to get full result set?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-search-console

everyone. I'm working with the Search Console API. I'm authenticated and getting data -- but not all that I'm hoping for.

The docs say that I can request 5,000 rows at a time. But when I set the setrowLimit parameter like this:

```
$request->setRowLimit(5000);
```

I get 127 rows returned, with text at the very bottom of the result set that says 'more elements...' -- almost as if it's a paginated result set.

How do I get to those 'more elements'?

Edit: At the top of my result set, I see this response;

```
array (size=5000)
```

So it definitely appears there are 5,000 results in the array, I just don't know how to get them all.

Comment: where does it say you can set row limit with that API I am not seeing any documentation or that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Please, post an example of your code. I set row limit to 5000 bit i don't have any problemi and never see the label "more elements". Where do you get this text? Into the array result?

Comment: It was my error. I was var_dumping the output to count the rows, which outputted up to 127 (I made the assumption that I was seeing what my script would 'see'). However, when I actually parsed the response, I could see there were 5,000 rows returned.

Edit: Have you found any resources for forming an argument like 'page contains foo-bar' with PHP? I've read the documentation and get what I'm supposed to do with dimension + operator + expression, but I can't figure out the syntax.